# How do I run installed packages using the shining panda plugin in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv, easy-install

I used the virtual env builder to create an enviroment. It seems this worked just fine.

I ran an easy_install on a python project. The next thing I want to do is run a command using that python project.

I ran easy_install 'my package'

on the next block I chose to run a cmd... but its not using the installed version in the virtual_env site packages using the panda plugin..

any advice would be wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In any block that you are planning on using a virtual environment you need to activate that environment - note that each block is effectively a separate shell so you cannot do this at the end of the block that you created the virtual environment.

So start each block that is supposed to use the env with:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Where *venv* is the environment name you used in the previous block.